# How can I bring up the progress GUI when running Client.SyncFiles in p4.net.api

Tags: c#, perforce, p4.net

Is there a way of spawning the progress GUI:
[image] (the one you would see if you do update from p4v), when running `Client.SyncFiles`?

I have also tried spawning `p4 sync` a `P4Command`, but I cannot see how I can pass global flags (to run `p4 -I sync -q`).

Thanks!

Comment: I have also tried spawning `p4 sync` a `P4Command`, but I cannot see how I can pass global flags (to run `p4 -I sync -q`).

Comment: also looks like `p4vc` doesn't support `sync` command at all

Comment: Which part of the GUI? The whole P4V? Why don't you just start it? I also don't understand why you would want to do that "when syncing". Maybe you want the cmdline output from the sync?

Comment: When I press the update button in P4V, it shows the progress window with a stop button and a progress bar - that's all the UI I want to bring up

Comment: Actually, I take it back about `p4 -I sync -q` - it shows a commandline progress - not the UI

Comment: I'm pretty sure that progress dialog is specific to P4V and there's no way to get it in isolation. I don't even know how you'd implement it in your application, since using a regular `p4 sync` command P4 doesn't tell you the number of files you're going to sync overall (hence you can't calculate the percentage).

Comment: Are there any analogues to ClientProgress in C++ API (http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api/chapter.methods.html#clientuser.createprogress)?